# Брать текст из textarea с другого сайта?

Tags: php, textarea

Доброе время суток, подскажите каким способом можно с помощью `php` можно загрузить страницу к примеру `sitename.ru/rsss.htm?&station1=230506` и вытащить только `textarea`

```
<textarea name="message" style="width:100%" rows="10">Бла бла</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться библиотекой `simple_html_dom`. Будет выглядеть примерно так

```
$html = str_get_html($data);
$res = $html->find('textarea [name=message]',0)->plaintext;
```

где `data` - загруженные `HTML` страницы

Comment: require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = "http://tarif.riccom.ru/rrtarif.htm?&station1=230506&station2=970001&cargo=416002&vagon_id=12&vagon_count=1"; 
$html=file_get_contents($url);
$htmls = str_get_html($html);
$res = $htmls->find('textarea [name=message]',0)->plaintext;
print_r($res);


тоже не прокатило

Comment: require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = "http://tarif.riccom.ru/rrtarif.htm?&station1=230506&station2=970001&cargo=416002&vagon_id=12&vagon_count=1"; 
$html=file_get_contents($url);
$htmls = str_get_html($html);
$res = $htmls->find('textarea',0);
//print_r($res);
echo $res->plaintext;

Answer (score 1):

Можно регулярным выражением.

```
$url='http://адрес';
$html=file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('/<textarea name="message" style="width:100%" rows="10">(.+)<\/textarea>/isu', $html, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Потом просто выбираете необходимый элемент массива.

Comment: Попробовал но в массиве получаю только Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )  Нету текста.

Answer (score 1):

Откуда страницу тащить?
Можно так:

```
$str = file_get_content(страница);
preg_match("#<textarea(?:[^>]+)>(.+?)<\/textarea>#is",$str,$match);
```

в `$match[1]` будет содержимое

Если сторонний сайт, то `file_get_content` может не прокатить...  тогда берем `curl`, получаем страничку и пользуемся представленной регуляркой...

Если `textarea` несколько на страничке, тогда `preg_match` заменить на `preg_match_all` и тогда на выходе будет их несколько

Comment: с curl тоже не прокатило (

Comment: $url = "http://tarif.riccom.ru/rrtarif.htm?&station1=230506&station2=970001&cargo=416002&vagon_id=12&vagon_count=1"; 
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all("#<textarea(?:[^>]+)>(.+?)<\/textarea>#is",$result,$match);
print_r($match);

Comment: ну... вы уж слишком простой вариант берете... а как же заголовки? юзер-агент хотя бы...
при таком подходе (с курл) не спешите регулярку пихать. сначала добейтесь получения страницы. что в $result у вас?

Comment: массив из  Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) , а если echo то вся страница но в массив не попадает текст из textarea

Comment: simple - можно но лишние "тяжести"
ну раз страничка получена дайте кусок кода из неё, где textarea

Comment: Спасибо решил с помощью simple_html_dom.

Comment: <td align="right">Сообщение:</td>
 <td><textarea name="message" style="width:100%" rows="10">ВАШ КОММЕНТАРИЙ
  
            
РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ РАСЧЕТА:
Срок доставки:                33 сут
Станция отправления:          230506, Купавна
Станция назначения:           970001, Хабаровск II
</textarea></td>

Comment: Стало интересно и я проверил :), работает так:

$result = '<td align="right">Сообщение:</td> <td><textarea name="message" style="width:100%" rows="10">ВАШ КОММЕНТАРИЙ

РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ РАСЧЕТА: Срок доставки: 33 сут Станция отправления: 230506, Купавна Станция назначения: 970001, Хабаровск II </textarea></td>';

preg_match_all("#<textarea(?:[^>]+)>(.+?)<\/textarea>#is",$result,$match);

НА ВЫХОДЕ:
$match[1][0] - это текст в textarea